# Go: split string by comma but ignore comma within double quotes

Tags: regex, go

I have input string separated by comma. But it may contains comma within double quotes which need to be ignored. Below is sample string

```
str := "\"age\": \"28\", \"favorite number\": \"26\", \"salary\": \"$1,234,108\""
```

Below is the code which I use to split on comma but it fails where comma is part of the string in double quotes.

```
s1 := strings.Split(s, "\"")
s2 := strings.Join(s1, "")
s3 := strings.Split(s2, ",")
```

So any thought how to fix this issue.

Comment: Your input string appears to be a fragment from JSON content, which begs the question of why aren't you using a parser?

Comment: Yes, its more of JSON string but colons are replaced with "\t" as some fields can have colon. Also post processing the string it is serialized into a JSON string.

Comment: Write a parser for that particular strange format.

Comment: `Yes, its more of JSON string but colons are replaced with "\t" as some fields can have colon` leads me to wonder if the given example is legit.

Comment: This is not just "splitting" a string. You must use a parser. Since this is a non-standard format, you'll have to write your own.

Comment: Could you specify what is the result that you want from this input string. Do you want to split it at commas, ignoring the commas in the strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will do what you want.

```
// SplitAtCommas split s at commas, ignoring commas in strings.
func SplitAtCommas(s string) []string {
    res := []string{}
    var beg int
    var inString bool

    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        if s[i] == ',' && !inString {
            res = append(res, s[beg:i])
            beg = i+1
        } else if s[i] == '"' {
            if !inString {
                inString = true
            } else if i > 0 && s[i-1] != '\\' {
                inString = false
            }
        }
    }
    return append(res, s[beg:])
}
```

A full example is available here: https://play.golang.org/p/f5jceIm4nbE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to get the key and value

```
package main

import (

"fmt"
"strings"

)

func main() {
  str := "\"age\": \"28\", \"favorite number\": \"26\", \"salary\": \"$1,234,108\""
  arr := strings.Split(str,`",`)
  for _, v := range arr {
     val := strings.Split(v,`:`)
     fmt.Println("Key:",val[0],"value:",val[1])
  }
}
```

Run in [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/89KiaqY1vBw)

Comment: no, this will bug if a string contains `:` or `\",`

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely correct. but his question includes just comma within the string So, I proposed this solution, otherwise regex will be a better solution here.